# How to override `location.href` in Electron to a custom URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron

#### Description

Is it possible to modify or override the perceived current location and origin in Electron.js?

I am loading a local .html file in Electron, and I need to manually override `location.href`, `document.domain`, and all other references to the current location to point to `https://example.com/my/page` in order for some external libraries (e.g. reCAPTCHA) to work with the local page.

Is it possible to set the current location to be `example.com`, *without* actually making a request to the remote URL, so that any javascript on the page *thinks* that the current URL is that, instead of `app://....`?

#### What I've tried

For my tests, I achieved it by running a MITM proxy that intercepts HTTPS requests, and instead of making a request to the origin, responds with a locally generated html page, which therefore I can inject my actual content into.

However, I don't want to go with this approach, and I was wondering if Electron could *natively* masquerade as a custom URL while loading local files, and report to any content un the page with the appropriate `location`/`origin`.

Comment: I don't know anything about what you intend to do but something is puzzling me: 
you said "responds with a locally generated html page, which therefore I can inject my actual content into". But to my sense you can inject a content into the origin page loaded in a webview for example with also adding it's own preload script. It doesn't answer to your question but perhaps it could point to another way of doing what you want......

Answer (score 0):

```js
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(filter, (details, callback) => {
    //console.log(details);
    //details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = 'MyAgent';
    details.requestHeaders['Origin'] = 'https://example.com/my/page';
    callback({cancel: false, requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders});
});
```

have you tried the above handler where you can modify the header origin parameter. Let me know if it. Different third party services will not work if your application is loaded using file protocal, you could also try loading/serving the html files using an http server which runs during electron app bootstrap. For this you can try serving it using an express server.

References :  https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6859